# How to retrieve Object name from Push topic API streaming

Tags: soql, javascript, streaming-api

I created a pushTopic for an object

```
pushTopic.Name = 'InvoiceStatementUpdates';

pushTopic.Query = 'SELECT Id, Name, Status__c, Description__c FROM Invoice_Statement__c';
```

From Salesforce Java Streaming APi, I get the output as

```
{event={createdDate=2017-10-12T17:10:42.677Z, replayId=5, type=undeleted}, sobject={Description__c=Java Client Test-2, status__c=Open, Id=a9O2F00000000iGUAQ, Name=INV-0001}}
```

Is there anyway I  can  get the object name(Invoice_Statement__c)   in the Streaming API output.

In the Output "Id=a9O2F00000000iGUAQ" is related to "Invoice_Statement__c" object but I am not sure how to get the mapping between those two dynamically.

Comment: You mean within Javascript, correct? I somehow had assumed initially that you needed this in Apex.

Comment: Either Java or JavaScript is fine

Comment: did you figure out how to get it?

Comment: I did code changes in EMP connector and I could work it out